# Unexpected output from mapPartitionsWithIndex

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
val r1 = sc.parallelize((1 to 100 by 1)).map(i => (i, i % 10))
val r2 = for(i <- 0 to 9) yield r1.filter(_._2 == i).repartition(2)

val tt = r2.map {r =>
    println(s"partitions ${r.getNumPartitions}")
    val t = r.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, p) => {
        val len = p.toList.size
        p.map(j => (j._1, j._2, i, len))
    })
    t
}.reduce(_ union _)
println (s"total ${tt.count}")
println(tt.collect().mkString("\n"))
```

My expectation was that the outer two `println` will produce `total 100` and print the tuples in the `tt` RDD as `(10, 0, 1, 5)` or so. But executing this in a spark shell gives `total 0` only. Why is the `tt` RDD empty. It's confusing me.  Note that the inner `println` does print `partitions 2` for every RDD in `r2`. I am using Spark 1.6.1

Answer (score 2):

Your problem here is in your `mapPartitions` lambda function -- you're consuming the partition iterator by converting it to a list, so it's empty when you invoke `p.map(j => (j._1, j._2, i, len))`!

Here's how you can fix it:

```
val t = r.mapPartitionsWithIndex((i, p) => {
    val elements = p.toArray
    val len = elements.length
    elements.iterator.map(j => (j._1, j._2, i, len))
})
```